# ESP8266 NodeMCU v3 basic questions

Tags: esp8266

Can somebody please tell me what is the operating voltage of ESP8266?

What is the A0 voltage range?

I am powering it up from USB (5v) and have a sensor that comes back with Analog value, to calculate it correctly I am asked to provide "Logical Voltage" value that is either 3300 or 5000 (3.3v or 5v). Sensor is connected to 3.3V port as there is no 5v port on the board.

What do I choose here 3300 or 5000 for NodeMCU V3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subtle clue is in the voltage that is available. That is, the only voltage provided on the board is 3.3v. That's a slight hint that the board might run at 3.3v. And you would be right in that assumption.

The ESP8266 chips, as are most modern MCUs more powerful than 8-bit, 3.3v devices.

So you would choose 3300 as your "Logical Voltage" value.  Or better still, measure the 3.3V and find exactly what it is and use that value x 1000 (for example 3317 or 3295).

Comment: Thank you @Majenko, this was really helpfull. Do you know by a chance what is the Range of voltage that this board can take on AD0?

Comment: 0v to 3.3v since 3.3v is the supply voltage.

Comment: Thank you very much Majenko! You saved my project with this :)